# How to use bind Cloudtable in java azure functions

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Is there a way to bind the table in java azure functions similar to c#

```
[FunctionName("TableInput")]
public static void Run(
[QueueTrigger("table-items")] string input, 
[Table("MyTable", "Http", "{queueTrigger}", Connection = 
"StorageConnectionAppSetting")] MyPoco poco, 
TraceWriter log)
{
...
}
```

Something like this? I dont want to use the azure storage library to manually fetch the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TableInput` annotation:

```java
@TableInput(name = "item", tableName = "MyTable", partitionKey = "Http", 
    rowKey = "{queueTrigger}", connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting") MyPojo pojo
```

See [example in Building Microsoft Azure Functions in Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/blob/734c0c55f70c80f6c361af2ef4bd8f778502dd42/README.md#inputs).

Comment: how do i retrieve all the rows with that partitionkey?

Comment: actually i need to retrieve all the rows with the partition key and update them based on some logic